# Correct syntax for inserting jQuery variable into 'style' attribute

Tags: jquery

`var heightMap = $('.sticky-panel-map').outerHeight(true);`

`var fillerMap = $('<div style="height: '+ heightMap +'"/>');`

I don't know if the syntax is wrong or what? `heightMap` isn't being applied, I'm getting this in Firebug:

`<div style=""></div>`

All good as mentioned in the comments I went with: `$("<div>").css("height", heightMap)`

Thanks

Comment: But why do you want to do it this way..why just not assign an id to ur div an use it..

Comment: what value are you getting in `heightMap` ??

Comment: Never mind I fixed it, i was forgetting the 'px' e.g. `var fillerMap = $('<div style="height: '+ heightMap +'px"/>');`

Comment: 404NotFound because it's dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id = "styleheight">
</div>
```

jQuery part

```
var heightMap = $('.sticky-panel-map').outerHeight(true) + 'px';
$('#styleheight').css('height',heightMap)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd rather inject the HTML via jQuery but it works fine with: `$('div').css('height',heightMap)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$("<div>").css("height", heightMap)
```

OR

```
$("<div>").height(heightMap)
```

are exactly equivalent. In general, unless jQuery has a more specialized function for it .css can be used to CRUD style entries. Take a look here: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Yeah I went with: `$("<div>").css("height", heightMap)`, thanks.

Comment: user1116204 if the answer was helpful please upvote it so others know

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('<div></div>').attr('style', 'height: ' + heightMap);`

Another option is `$('<div></div>').height(heightMap);`

Also, look here: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Comment: Yeah I went with: `$("<div>").css("height", heightMap)`, thanks.